# wired connect eth0 & eth1, how to let packet send to eth0 received from eth1 on same pc

Tags: linux, networking

I have a two ports PCI-E network card.
two interface eth0 eth1.
I wired connect this two port.

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.1
ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.2
```

how to config route table, to let `ping 10.0.0.2`
packet send out eth0, then received back from eth1